# Можно ли сказать «без вести канул»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Можно ли сказать или написать ***без вести канул***?

Comment: Лола, а Вы немка?

Comment: вообще фразеологизм "пропасть без вести", а глагол  кануть, по-моему, предполагает наличие после себя предлога "в"

Comment: а немецкое "nie mehr", по-моему, ложится на русский как "никогда больше"

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

[**кануть**](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Ozhegov-term-11602.htm) [МАС] -ну, -нешь; сов.
3. перен.
**Пропасть, исчезнуть, скрыться.**
*Ночью Васька ушел — и уж больше не возвращался, — так и **канул**.* Серафимович, Мышиное царство.
{Мария Ипполитовна:} *В самом деле, ушел человек, сказал вернется через час-полтора… — и **канул**.* Салынский, Ложь для узкого круга.
*Куда же он **канул**, где обретался после краха мельницы?* Бек, Талант.

Как будто, словно в воду канул; как в воду канул; кануть в лету.

Теоретически (по смыслу) так сказать можно: без вести пропал, без вести исчез, без вести скрылся. Мне думается, что ошибки нет.

*Вы, кто **без вести канул** в бою,

Кто за нас расплатился собою,

Я о вас своё слово пою!

Выходите из тени, герои!

Вы, кто без вести канул в бою.*
[Г. Косточаков. Полнарода ушло на войну](https://www.10kanal.ru/stixiya2206-mp4_snapshot_00-43_2015-06-22_13-52-54)

*Отправившись в свою очередную экспедицию, вся группа Пожарского **канула без вести** севернее Припяти, где-то на переходе...* (Р. Глушков. Дрожь земли)